# Identify Dog-eat-dog society story

Tags: dystopia, story-identification

This story was set in an over-crowded 'hot-house' of a city, a dog-eat-dog society where only the most competitive individuals survive and rise to power.The revelation is that another society then take these individuals out of the city to use in their own society - a kind of alpha-male farm. Ring any bells? I read it probably in the early 1980s.

Comment: I would name it: "Racing dogs"

Comment: Flagged as too vague.  Frankly, this question sounds like a joke where someone wondered, "What answers will we get to an extremely open-ended sci-fi question?"

Comment: By "too vague" do you mean there are two or more stories that fit the description? Could you kindly name one of them?

Comment: Sounds a bit like The Dosadi Experiment by Frank Herbert - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dosadi_Experiment

Comment: Sounds a bit like "Ballroom of the Skies" by John D. MacDonald.

Comment: The second half of it sounds a bit like "This Perfect day".(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Perfect_Day)

Comment: Reminded me of "Taken" by Erin Bowman (mostly the second half, one society harvesting another for use as soldiers)